# Blowing-up an ordinary double point, then contracting the exceptional locus to a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, singularity-theory, blow-ups

Let $X\subset\mathbb P^4$ a projective hypersurface with an ordinary double point at $o\in X$.

Blow-up $\mathbb P^4$ at $o$ and let $E\simeq\mathbb P^3$ the exceptional divisor of this blow-up. Consider the strict transform $\widetilde X$ of $X$. Then, it is easy to verify that $Y=\widetilde X\cap E$ is a quadric hypersurface in $E\simeq\mathbb P^3$, thus isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1$.

Now, take an hyperplane (if you want, generic) section $C$ of $Y$ in $E$, that is $C=Y\cap H(\simeq\mathbb P^1)$, where $H$ is a hyperplane in $E\simeq\mathbb P^3$. Obviously, the curve $C$ meets each line of the two rulings of $Y$ in exactly one point. So, choose one ruling and define the obvious morphism $\varphi\colon Y\to C$ obtained by collapsing any line of the choosen ruling to its intersection point with $C$.

**Here is my question.**

Does there exist a *smooth* projective variety $\overline X$, containing a curve isomorphic to $C$ (which I still call $C$), and a regular morphism $\Phi\colon\widetilde X\to\overline X$ such that:

- $\Phi|_{\widetilde X\setminus Y}\colon\widetilde X\setminus Y\quad\overset{\simeq}\to\quad\overline X\setminus C$
- $\Phi|_{Y}\colon Y\to C$ is the $\varphi$ above.

I guess this is very classical, but I wasn't able to find it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess the answer in **no** when $\deg(X) \geq 3$.

In fact, in this case Griffiths showed that the two rulings $L_1$ and $L_2$ in $E$ are *numerically equivalent* in $\widetilde{X}$ (although not algebraically equivalent in general), so the corresponding $K_{\widetilde{X}}$-negative rays $R_1$ and $R_2$ in the Mori cone of $\widetilde{X}$ coincide.

It follows that the contraction of $R_1$ is actually the contraction of the whole quadric, that is it is not possible to contract the two rulings separately.

The situation is very subtle: in fact, the completed local ring $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,o}$ is *not* factorial, but the fact that $L_1$ is numerically equivalent to $L_2$ implies that $\mathcal{O}_{X,o}$ is factorial.

See [Debarre, Higher Dimensional Algebraic Geometry, p. 160] and the references given therein.

Comment: Dear Francesco, I don't really understand your answer... The problem is fairly local (around the isolated double point), so how can the degree of the hypersurface influence the answer?

Comment: The (subtle) point is really this: the problem is *not* a local one. When you have a smooth threefold $Y$ containing a quadric $Q$ with normal bundle $\mathcal{O}_Q(-1, -1)$, then two things can happen: either the two rulings of $Q$ are numerically equivalent in $Y$ or they are not. Only in the latter case you can contract the ruling separately and it is *impossible* to tell, locally analytically, the difference between the two cases (see Debarre's book, top of page 161). 

Comment: Regarding your problem, Griffits showed that the two rulings in the exceptional divisor are numerically equivalent in $\widetilde{X}$ when $d \geq 3$, so (unless X is a quadric threefold) one cannot contracts separately the rulings. This is also explained by Debarre.

Comment: On the other hand... I think that in the analytic category this should always work, isn't it?

Comment: Actually I do not know. I should think about it

Comment: Ok, I'll think about it too. Anyway I am reading the paper of Griffiths, and I can't really find what Debarre states in his book...

Comment: Nevermind, found it!.